# how to deploy a project on client's computer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment, deployment-project

I have a built a .**net application** using **visual studio**.
This application is coded in **C#** and uses **SQLSERVER** for database purposes(storage,retrieval and manipulation of data).

Please tell me **how to give this application to client**?

Do I have to install **.net framework** on client's computer..?
Do I need to install complete **sqlserver** on client's computer to access database?
or 
giving the **.exe** file to client would be okay to solve the purpose..?

help please...

Answer (score 1):

client needs .Net, SQl-Server and the .exe and .dlls from \Source\bin\Release.

Comment: write the programm for SQLite or SQLCompact ;) then the client just needs .NET and the dlls and exe from the release-folder

Answer (score 0):

Your application has several dependencies - the .net framework and it will need a SQL Server to access its data.

You will need to have both the framework setup on their computer, make sure they have a SQL server with the database and data you have setup on it (which is accessible to the application) and the exe you have created.

Look into setup projects - these will allow you to make sure that all prerequisites for you application (ddls and framework) are installed (and they may even install them). They will not help with the SQL Server side - you will still need to create scripts that generate you database and the initial data in it.

Comment: I searched for the .net framework on internet.
I got 2 files: one is of just 2.7MB(Microsoft.com) and other one was of 48MB(brothersoft.com).
which one would be correct to install on client's computer..?

Comment: @Akshay - The 2.7Mb file is the web installer - it will download and install only what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Visual Studio's [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx) deployment method, which comes pre-built into most every version of Visual Studio, not to mention it's free.

In Visual Studio, simply "Publish" your project. You'll be given options on how you'd like to deploy (via web, standalone, etc). The installer automatically makes sure the client has the correct version of the .NET Framework, as well, which is handy. I'm not sure about SQLServer, though, you'd have to test that theory out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

the following steps might help:

1. use a setup project to deploy your solution
2. add prerequisites in the setup bootstrapper to whatever external depedencies you are using (.net framework, sql server)
3. depending on the version of the .net framework used you may or may not have to install it, as it is possible to already exist on the client's computer.
4. sql server needs to be installed (i doubt the client has it already).
5. your app must be configured in order to use the server installed.
6. other prerequisites (such as libraries, resources etc.) can be included in your app's setup.
7. giving the exe file to the client won't help at all.